# Dynamically setting pl/sql code in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have 2 regions in a page, both regions are classic reports displayed as cards. The first report is of team names(built from pl/sql query of a table with column's id, team_name) and the second report is of players(built from pl/sql query of a table with column's id, player_name, team_name & goals scored). Now when I click on a team card in the first region, the second region should only show players of that team which means the where clause in the second region should be changed dynamically. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is parent-child relationship, or in Oracle APEX terms, Master-Detail.
So what you will do is make the team report the Master, and Players report the Detail.

I think there is a whole lot of documentation about this online so now that you know what you are looking for you should be able to figure things out. If you try and still cant make it work let me know.